# TFS - not able to download files

Tags: tfs

In our project solution we done the changes in 5 files (only content change) and the change set number is NNNNN, we want to download those 5 files only. We can get entire solution files upto this change set. Due to content change we want those files only instead of getting all other files like dll or *.CS files.

In other source control the view history displays the affected files, there is a provision to export those files into folder rather than entire solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a little PowerShell/.Net code to do this or you can use the [TFS Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1).  There is a command line tfpt.exe and you can use the getcs flag

```
tfpt getcs /changeset:12
```

There is a decent write up of the process [here](http://alexpeta.ro/blog/post/exporting-a-changeset-in-team-foundation-server-tfs-using-team-foundation-power-tools-tfpt)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reploy

Comment: verified in powershell but i want to download the file in my local machine folder, it replacing the files in the tfs mapped foler

Comment: Use another workspace to download only the files you want

Comment: Hi, using another work space will download all the files, not the files checked in for that changeset instead of that will give the files checked in before/previous also

Comment: Create a new Workspace. Map it to a location on your local machine BUT DO NOT GET LATEST. Open a command prompt.  Navigate to that newly created folder.  Run tfpt.exe getcs.  Only the files in that changeset will be downloaded to your local machine.

Comment: Thank you, I'm able to get the expected result